# How to create a table of timestamp for different entity excluding different range to timestamp in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a database with different types of incident information on road segment. Sample of data is shown in the following table 1.

[image]

I have one more table which contains the timestamp of whole 2011 with one minute interval for each segment. Sample data is shown in the following table 2.

[image]

One segment can have impacts from multiple incidents. Therefore I want to create a table similar to table 2 i.e. it will have timestamp information for all 100 segments except those portions where there is incident. For example segment 2 is in both incident 1 and incident 2. Therefore in table 3 for segment 2 timestamp will be from 2011-01-01 00:00:58 to 2011-12-31 23:59:58 except 2011-01-01 13:45:00 - 2011-01-01 14:47:00 and 2011-02-01 13:33:00 - 2011-02-01 15:05:00.

Comment: Some sample table and result rows might help clarify your question. Are you looking for a solution that works on all of the SQL Server versions with which your question is tagged?

Comment: Output will be timestamp for whole 2011 for each each segment (according to sample table 2 there will be 100 segments) except those time period when there is an incident but if there is no incident on the segment then there will be no exclusion. Actually output table will be based on timestamp and it is very big thats why I explained it instead of showing.

Comment: create your schema using SQL fiddle, and input some sample data and expected results. http://sqlfiddle.com/  sample data. this helps your questions answered quickly

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to Exclude all incidents with segments and show only unhandled

```
CREATE Table INCIDENS 
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) , 
    INCIDENT  VARCHAR(255) 
    
)
CREATE TABLE INCIDENTLOCATION 
(
    INCIDENT  VARCHAR(255) , 
    SGMENT  VARCHAR(255) , 
    [STARATON] DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    [ENDSON] DATETIME NOT NULL , 
)


SELECT I.*  , S.* 
FROM INCIDENS I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN INCIDENTLOCATION S ON I.INCIDENT = S.INCIDENT
WHERE I.INCIDENT IS NULL
```